# MariaDB freezes with no visible reason

Tags: performance, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

MariaDB server experiences some sort of freezes happening sporadically with no visible reason or connection to outside factors (load, etc). After a thorough investigation the common picture for those freezes is the following:

1. There are many different queries (all of them are lightweight select using an index or plain inserts) that got frozen waiting for something.
2. After this *something* is over, queries are processed pretty fast.
3. Freeze lasts for about 5-10 seconds.

---

```
---TRANSACTION 35712946030, not started
...
--TRANSACTION 35712946031, not started flushing log
...
---TRANSACTION 35712945941, not started
...
---TRANSACTION 35712945772, not started flushing log
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
MySQL thread id 1904927, OS thread handle 0x7f437b04b700, query id 88121305 localhost dbu_user query end
INSERT INTO t_log <just plain values>
...
---TRANSACTION 35712945932, not started flushing log
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
MySQL thread id 1904895, OS thread handle 0x7f4371568700, query id 88121792 localhost dbu_user query end
INSERT INTO t_log <just plain values>
...
---TRANSACTION 35712945902, not started flushing log
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
MySQL thread id 1904887, OS thread handle 0x7f3dace37700, query id 88121710 localhost dbu_user query end
INSERT INTO t_log <just plain values>
...
---TRANSACTION 35712946032, not started
MySQL thread id 1904891, OS thread handle 0x7f3de3d9d700, query id 88122203 localhost dbu_user 
---TRANSACTION 35712946047, not started
MySQL thread id 1904899, OS thread handle 0x7f437da37700, query id 88122191 localhost dbu_user 
---TRANSACTION 35712945339, not started
MySQL thread id 1904898, OS thread handle 0x7f3de3f14700, query id 88122121 localhost dbu_user
...
```

So every INSERT transaction says:

```
not started flushing log
```

Other says:

```
not started
```

More of *SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS*:

```
MySQL thread id 1, OS thread handle 0x7f437dacd700, query id 0 Waiting for requests
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 1; buffer pool: 1
6994083 OS file reads, 2285417 OS file writes, 234347 OS fsyncs
11.60 reads/s, 16384 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s

--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
0 RW transactions active inside InnoDB
0 RO transactions active inside InnoDB
0 out of 1000 descriptors used
Main thread process no. 1493, id 139904004646656, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 5295384, updated 429036, deleted 692576, read 1748285626
12.60 inserts/s, 1.55 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 27032.25 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
```

Most of the times there is the following row for *main process*:

```
Main thread process no. 1493, id 139904004646656, state: flushing log
```

Header says:

```
=====================================
2021-05-21 17:39:59 7f3df0fff700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 17 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 50917 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 253 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 51168
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 96271
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 282014
Mutex spin waits 1951655, rounds 3496412, OS waits 64297
RW-shared spins 238185, rounds 1674512, OS waits 21055
RW-excl spins 81399, rounds 1006087, OS waits 10118
Spin rounds per wait: 1.79 mutex, 7.03 RW-shared, 12.36 RW-excl
```

**SELECT VERSION():**

```
VERSION()
10.1.48-MariaDB-0+deb9u2
```

**SHOW GLOBAL STATUS:**

```
Variable_name   Value
***
Aria_pagecache_blocks_not_flushed   0
Aria_pagecache_blocks_unused    15706
Aria_pagecache_blocks_used  15706
Aria_pagecache_read_requests    338868768
Aria_pagecache_reads    30678281
Aria_pagecache_write_requests   69095480
Aria_pagecache_writes   370410
Aria_transaction_log_syncs  13
Binlog_commits  0
Binlog_group_commits    0
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_count   0
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_lock_wait   0
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_timeout 0
Binlog_snapshot_file    
Binlog_snapshot_position    0
Binlog_bytes_written    0
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Busy_time   0.000000
Bytes_received  18590540106
Bytes_sent  181560472399
Com_admin_commands  3
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 59
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_analyze 0
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_begin   15
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  0
Com_change_db   6264
Com_change_master   0
Com_check   0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  14
Com_compound_sql    0
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_role 0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    1
Com_create_temporary_table  0
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 0
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete  3
Com_delete_multi    4
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_role   0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  1
Com_drop_temporary_table    0
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 2
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_flush   0
Com_get_diagnostics 0
Com_grant   0
Com_grant_role  0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  1967555
Com_insert_select   847
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    3
Com_load    0
Com_lock_tables 0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge   0
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   1
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 1
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_revoke_role 0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   2
Com_savepoint   1
Com_select  29384364
Com_set_option  4278953
Com_show_authors    0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets   0
Com_show_collations 50
Com_show_contributors   0
Com_show_create_db  131
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   30281755
Com_show_create_trigger 0
Com_show_databases  6
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  20
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_events 30
Com_show_explain    0
Com_show_fields 30282518
Com_show_function_status    1
Com_show_generic    0
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   119
Com_show_master_status  0
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_status   1
Com_show_processlist    116
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    3
Com_show_slave_status   3
Com_show_status 16
Com_show_storage_engines    6
Com_show_table_status   104
Com_show_tables 0
Com_show_triggers   22
Com_show_variables  26
Com_show_warnings   141
Com_shutdown    0
Com_signal  0
Com_start_all_slaves    0
Com_start_slave 0
Com_stmt_close  0
Com_stmt_execute    0
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    0
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_stop_all_slaves 0
Com_stop_slave  0
Com_truncate    6
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   1
Com_update  319512
Com_update_multi    788
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression OFF
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal  0
Connection_errors_max_connections   0
Connection_errors_peer_address  0
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0
Connections 2141938
Cpu_time    0.000000
Created_tmp_disk_tables 30318872
Created_tmp_files   38088
Created_tmp_tables  36812016
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Delete_scan 1
Empty_queries   6291088
Executed_events 0
Executed_triggers   0
Feature_delay_key_write 0
Feature_dynamic_columns 0
Feature_fulltext    0
Feature_gis 0
Feature_locale  0
Feature_subquery    2011
Feature_timezone    3
Feature_trigger 1
Feature_xml 0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  31637906
Handler_delete  692578
Handler_discover    52
Handler_external_lock   0
Handler_icp_attempts    19307656516
Handler_icp_match   62206365
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_mrr_key_refills 0
Handler_mrr_rowid_refills   0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  3284385
Handler_read_key    258101790
Handler_read_last   4146611
Handler_read_next   1298969205
Handler_read_prev   38190
Handler_read_retry  0
Handler_read_rnd    482143308
Handler_read_rnd_deleted    16887
Handler_read_rnd_next   446790716
Handler_rollback    4
Handler_savepoint   1
Handler_savepoint_rollback  2
Handler_tmp_update  29778550
Handler_tmp_write   359275356
Handler_update  440384
Handler_write   23298394
Innodb_available_undo_logs  128
Innodb_background_log_sync  57342
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   21139406848
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  204390400
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status  Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status  Loading buffer pool(s) not yet started
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   1290247
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  12475
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    275633
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   20453
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_lru_flushed    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_not_young 133262961
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_young 6416964
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_old    475882
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  1310700
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   635595
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    3823266111
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    6800967
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    99906
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   41795423
Innodb_checkpoint_age   198686598
Innodb_checkpoint_max_age   3478212404
Innodb_data_fsyncs  253776
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    122639356416
Innodb_data_reads   7485133
Innodb_data_writes  2394663
Innodb_data_written 12082536448
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  277234
Innodb_dblwr_writes 77724
Innodb_deadlocks    0
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins ON
Innodb_history_list_length  29
Innodb_ibuf_discarded_delete_marks  0
Innodb_ibuf_discarded_deletes   0
Innodb_ibuf_discarded_inserts   0
Innodb_ibuf_free_list   232719
Innodb_ibuf_merged_delete_marks 1242585
Innodb_ibuf_merged_deletes  126524
Innodb_ibuf_merged_inserts  63001
Innodb_ibuf_merges  52159
Innodb_ibuf_segment_size    232721
Innodb_ibuf_size    1
Innodb_log_waits    1
Innodb_log_write_requests   4463179
Innodb_log_writes   2031869
Innodb_lsn_current  2668534004820
Innodb_lsn_flushed  2668534003645
Innodb_lsn_last_checkpoint  2668335318222
Innodb_master_thread_active_loops   57090
Innodb_master_thread_idle_loops 253
Innodb_max_trx_id   35716233897
Innodb_mem_adaptive_hash    339996064
Innodb_mem_dictionary   85658368
Innodb_mem_total    22481469440
Innodb_mutex_os_waits   71063
Innodb_mutex_spin_rounds    3743636
Innodb_mutex_spin_waits 2067078
Innodb_oldest_view_low_limit_trx_id 0
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    64283
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   2992949248
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    62985
Innodb_pages_read   7484347
Innodb_pages0_read  425
Innodb_pages_written    277234
Innodb_purge_trx_id 35716233820
Innodb_purge_undo_no    0
Innodb_read_views_memory    984
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    526
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    37
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    282
Innodb_row_lock_waits   14
Innodb_rows_deleted 692576
Innodb_rows_inserted    5357728
Innodb_rows_read    1901348483
Innodb_rows_updated 440384
Innodb_system_rows_deleted  0
Innodb_system_rows_inserted 0
Innodb_system_rows_read 0
Innodb_system_rows_updated  0
Innodb_s_lock_os_waits  21170
Innodb_s_lock_spin_rounds   1678379
Innodb_s_lock_spin_waits    238517
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Innodb_x_lock_os_waits  10269
Innodb_x_lock_spin_rounds   1011254
Innodb_x_lock_spin_waits    81605
Innodb_page_compression_saved   0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect512    0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect1024   0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect2048   0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect4096   0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect8192   0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect16384  0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect32768  0
Innodb_num_index_pages_written  323915
Innodb_num_non_index_pages_written  2069541
Innodb_num_pages_page_compressed    0
Innodb_num_page_compressed_trim_op  0
Innodb_num_page_compressed_trim_op_saved    0
Innodb_num_pages_page_decompressed  0
Innodb_num_pages_page_compression_error 0
Innodb_num_pages_encrypted  0
Innodb_num_pages_decrypted  0
Innodb_have_lz4 OFF
Innodb_have_lzo OFF
Innodb_have_lzma    OFF
Innodb_have_bzip2   OFF
Innodb_have_snappy  OFF
Innodb_defragment_compression_failures  0
Innodb_defragment_failures  0
Innodb_defragment_count 0
Innodb_onlineddl_rowlog_rows    0
Innodb_onlineddl_rowlog_pct_used    0
Innodb_onlineddl_pct_progress   0
Innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads  232038557
Innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads_avoided  0
Innodb_buffered_aio_submitted   635595
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_read_from_cache    0
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_read_from_disk 0
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_modified   0
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_flushed    0
Innodb_encryption_rotation_estimated_iops   0
Innodb_encryption_key_rotation_list_length  0
Innodb_encryption_n_merge_blocks_encrypted  0
Innodb_encryption_n_merge_blocks_decrypted  0
Innodb_encryption_n_rowlog_blocks_encrypted 0
Innodb_encryption_n_rowlog_blocks_decrypted 0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_reorganizations    0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_splits 0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_underflow   0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_out_of_filespace    0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_missing_index   0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_unknown 0
Innodb_encryption_num_key_requests  0
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   53569
Key_blocks_used 9
Key_blocks_warm 0
Key_read_requests   85795
Key_reads   9
Key_write_requests  0
Key_writes  0
Last_query_cost 0.000000
Master_gtid_wait_count  0
Master_gtid_wait_time   0
Master_gtid_wait_timeouts   0
Max_statement_time_exceeded 0
Max_used_connections    149
Memory_used 244375568
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files  132
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  413
Open_tables 867
Opened_files    121314326
Opened_plugin_libraries 0
Opened_table_definitions    452
Opened_tables   1031
Opened_views    1695
***
Prepared_stmt_count 0
Qcache_free_blocks  1
Qcache_free_memory  1031336
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   0
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 1
Queries 98665350
Questions   98665350
Rows_read   1901287392
Rows_sent   732824967
Rows_tmp_read   499084097
Rpl_status  AUTH_MASTER
Select_full_join    0
Select_full_range_join  17548
Select_range    9003432
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 30293630
***
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    11828
Sort_merge_passes   19804
Sort_priority_queue_sorts   869093
Sort_range  5142865
Sort_rows   485949805
Sort_scan   6526377
***
Subquery_cache_hit  8
Subquery_cache_miss 5517
Syncs   36
Table_locks_immediate   55939785
Table_locks_waited  0
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    4096
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threadpool_idle_threads 21
Threadpool_threads  24
Threads_cached  0
Threads_connected   11
Threads_created 2664
Threads_running 3
Update_scan 48
Uptime  61512
Uptime_since_flush_status   61512
***
```

my.cnf is pretty standard, InnoDB settings:

```
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20G
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 20
innodb_log_file_size = 2G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
```

Some output from *mysqltuner.pl*:

```
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 17h 14m 39s (99M q [1K qps], 2M conn, TX: 170G, RX: 17G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 92% / 8%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 62.8G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 29.3G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 20.5G global + 34.9M per thread (256 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 105M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 25.6G (40.82% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 29.3G (46.63% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (11K/99M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 58% (149/256)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (16/2163778)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (19K temp sorts / 11M sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 82% (30M on disk / 37M total)
[--] Thread cache not used with thread_handling=pool-of-threads
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 84% (868 open / 1K opened)
[OK] table_definition_cache(800) is upper than number of tables(491)
[OK] Open file limit used: 5% (132/2K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (56M immediate / 56M locks)
```

**InnoDB Metrics:**

```
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 20.0G/193.6G
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 2.0G * 2/20.0G should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 20
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.82% (3853979630 hits/ 3860826332 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 54.38% (2430712 hits/ 4470120 total)
[!!] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (1 waits / 2039408 writes)
```

Everything seems fine, so I must be missing something out. Asking for advice.

**UPDATE.** Some extra weird data and mutex stats:

```
=====================================
2021-05-22 21:17:29 7fb9de7ff700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 16 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 46933 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 26232 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 73161
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 83146
--Thread 140435913168640 has waited at trx0sys.ic line 103 for 4.0000 seconds the semaphore:
X-lock (wait_ex) on RW-latch at 0x7fbf117fe968 '&block->lock'
a writer (thread id 140435913168640) has reserved it in mode  wait exclusive
number of readers 1, waiters flag 0, lock_word: ffffffffffffffff
Last time read locked in file buf0flu.cc line 1126
Last time write locked in file trx0sys.ic line 103
Holder thread 0 file not yet reserved line 0
--Thread 140435783866112 has waited at trx0trx.cc line 1057 for 4.0000 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x7fbf66bbc068 '&trx_sys->mutex', lock var 1
Last time reserved by thread 140435913168640 in file not yet reserved line 0, waiters flag 1
--Thread 140459985676032 has waited at trx0trx.cc line 1057 for 4.0000 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x7fbf66bbc068 '&trx_sys->mutex', lock var 1
Last time reserved by thread 140435913168640 in file not yet reserved line 0, waiters flag 1
--Thread 140435788166912 has waited at trx0trx.cc line 1057 for 4.0000 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x7fbf66bbc068 '&trx_sys->mutex', lock var 1
Last time reserved by thread 140435913168640 in file not yet reserved line 0, waiters flag 1
--Thread 140435799533312 has waited at trx0trx.cc line 1057 for 4.0000 seconds the semaphore:
... (post length limits)
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 171303
Mutex spin waits 566839, rounds 1843729, OS waits 48137
RW-shared spins 954015, rounds 4867601, OS waits 18698
RW-excl spins 247858, rounds 2764788, OS waits 14386
Spin rounds per wait: 3.25 mutex, 5.10 RW-shared, 11.15 RW-excl
```

**Mutex stats:**

```
show engine innodb mutex
Type    Name    Status
...
InnoDB  &ibuf_mutex os_waits=8
InnoDB  &dict_sys->mutex    os_waits=152
InnoDB  &trx_sys->mutex os_waits=3802
InnoDB  &lock_sys->mutex    os_waits=95
InnoDB  &log_sys->mutex os_waits=11308
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=1613
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=7
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=2599
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=22
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=1406
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=7
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=8609
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=63
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=428
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=3
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=1317
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=445
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=1
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=3218
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=3
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=519
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=3
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=628
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=15
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=1738
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=4
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=4458
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=18
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=362
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=4
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=214
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=2
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=175
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=1
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=1310
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=5
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=1268
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=15
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=110
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=1
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=80
InnoDB  &buf_pool->flush_state_mutex    os_waits=497
InnoDB  &buf_pool->LRU_list_mutex   os_waits=4
InnoDB  &fil_system->mutex  os_waits=157
InnoDB  &srv_sys.mutex  os_waits=59
InnoDB  combined &block->mutex  os_waits=129
InnoDB  &new_index->lock    os_waits=2
InnoDB  &new_index->lock    os_waits=274
InnoDB  &new_index->lock    os_waits=332
InnoDB  &new_index->lock    os_waits=480
InnoDB  &new_index->lock    os_waits=4
InnoDB  &new_index->lock    os_waits=2
InnoDB  &new_index->lock    os_waits=11
InnoDB  &new_index->lock    os_waits=3
InnoDB  &new_index->lock    os_waits=3
InnoDB  &new_index->lock    os_waits=484
InnoDB  &new_index->lock    os_waits=1
InnoDB  &new_index->lock    os_waits=1
InnoDB  &space->latch   os_waits=17
InnoDB  &space->latch   os_waits=2
InnoDB  &space->latch   os_waits=1
InnoDB  &new_index->lock    os_waits=28
InnoDB  &dict_operation_lock    os_waits=78
InnoDB  &log_sys->checkpoint_lock   os_waits=5379
InnoDB  &btr_search_latch_arr[i]    os_waits=16938
InnoDB  table->sync_obj.rw_locks + i    os_waits=13
InnoDB  table->sync_obj.rw_locks + i    os_waits=6
InnoDB  table->sync_obj.rw_locks + i    os_waits=1
InnoDB  table->sync_obj.rw_locks + i    os_waits=8
InnoDB  table->sync_obj.rw_locks + i    os_waits=5
InnoDB  table->sync_obj.rw_locks + i    os_waits=1
InnoDB  table->sync_obj.rw_locks + i    os_waits=23
InnoDB  table->sync_obj.rw_locks + i    os_waits=5
InnoDB  table->sync_obj.rw_locks + i    os_waits=10
InnoDB  table->sync_obj.rw_locks + i    os_waits=6
InnoDB  combined &block->lock   os_waits=2609
```

**UPDATE (following *Rick James* answer).** Thanks for the directions on tackling the problem, has already switched long_query_time to 1sec.

The weirdest thing about the case is that there is no visible link to any activity or parameter external to the database. It happens under different amounts of load, both low and medium. The following queries take more than a second to complete (according to slow log):

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `tbl_xyz`;

SELECT * FROM `tbl_index` `t` WHERE `t`.`term`='weird'; // term is a PK
```

I know my system inside out, each and every query was thoroughly designed, tested, stress-tested, and watched closely after being deployed to production. The system handles pretty heavy tasks during nightly jobs just fine.

These freezes/stalls are happening unpredictably and they don't seem to be connected with queries being executed on the database. Sounds crazy? That's exactly how it is.

I was thinking of a bug, but I don't have any idea of how to prove it. The database is updated to the latest available for Debian Stretch: 10.1.48-MariaDB-0+deb9u2.

Hardware fault was an option too, but monitoring shows no signs of it.

My backup plan is to upgrade to 10.3.27-0+deb10u1, which requires some heavy maintenance activity. Keeping it as a last resort.

**P.S.** There was a hardware issue (SSD) about a month ago. Has done *mysqlanalyze/mysqlcheck*, recovered one of the tables (by redeploying it from scratch), everything is in OK status since then. Not sure if it has any effect of happening now, but putting it there just in case.

Comment: 10.1 was released 6 years ago (2015) and reached EOL last year.  (10.3 was in 2018.)  Also, the more releases you upgrade past, the harder the upgrade can be.  So, I recommend upgrading soon.

Comment: @RickJames I am totally up to it, but it would require an OS upgrade as well, so it could only be done within a certain maintenance window.

Comment: And there are similar reasons not to let the OS get "too old".  Consider moving to a Primary-Replica (aka Master-Slave) setup; this may shrink the maintenance window in the future.

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

If it is easy to 'catch it in the act', get `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` when it locks up.  The queries going at that time *may* provide sufficient info to spot the problem.  Ignore any "Sleep" threads.  The villain is probably one of the ones with the oldest "Time" (aside from system processes).

Always have the slowlog turned on.

Since the freeze usually lasts more than 5 seconds, any setting for `long_query_time` less than 5 is advised.  (I recommend "1".)

Then, *after* the next 'freeze', run `pt-query-digest` with the slowlog.  It should several queries that took "too long".  One will be the villain; the rest will be 'victims' of the freeze.  As you experienced, many will terminate at about the same time.  Look in the raw slowlog to see which one was first.  It is likely to be the villain.  (Queries are added to the slowlog as they *finish*.)

Check `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and `SHOW VARIABLES`.  (I don't expect anything to need tuning.)

More on those topics:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

Comment: Thanks for the comment, has already lowered *long_query_time* to 1sec. Added more comments to the OP.

Comment: "term is a PK" -- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  If `term` is not the first column in the PK, there is a problem.

Comment: It's a single-column PK. I know of the prefix principle for compound keys and it's not it. There are a bunch of different queries targeting different tables all of them lasting for 1+ seconds. Query design is not the issue here or it would have fired long ago.

Comment: @user1065145 - True.  Each query could be optimal.  But sometimes the combination of queries is where the real problem is.  Much of what I am suggesting is looking for hints of a combination.  One example:  When more than a hundred queries are _running_ simultaneously, they may stumble over each other -- leading to a 1-second time for a perfectly optimized query.  Another example:  A rogue query that locks many rows of a table _may_ trigger delays in other threads.

Comment: That is, look for what _else_ was running when that point-query on `term` was slowed to 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Does your system log every thing to syslog? If so, is your syslog stalling or rate limiting? If syslog stalls for whatever reason, it can cause [MariaDB to freeze](https://shatteredsilicon.net/dbas-inconceivable-tales-mystery-of-the-freezing-mariadb-database/) up while trying it's output is going to syslog.

Disclosure: I wrote the referenced article.